# How to import proto definitions when using Proto DataStore?

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, android-jetpack-datastore

### The enum I want to import in other .proto files

```
// spc/main/proto/battery_saver_mode_enum.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.freephoenix888.savemylife";
option java_multiple_files = false;

enum BatterySaverMode {
  Disabled = 0;
  Enabled = 1;
  Adaptive = 2;
}
```

### The way I try to import it

```
// src/main/proto/location_preferences.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "battery_saver_mode_enum.proto";

option java_package = "com.freephoenix888.savemylife";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message LocationPreferences {
  bool isLocationSharingEnabled = 1;
  BatterySaverMode BatterySaverMode = 2;
}
```

### Error

```
Cannot resolve import 'battery_saver_mode_enum.proto'
```

[image: Cannot resolve import 'battery_saver_mode_enum.proto' error]

### My attempts to fix this

When I try Andriod Studio autocomplete I have this:
[image]

When I try to use the relative path `import "./battery_saver_mode_enum.proto";`
I get the error `Backslashes, consecutive slashes, ., and .. are not allowed in the virtual path`

I have .proto files in the `src/main/proto` folder because every Proto DataStore guide says to do so. If I pul them in another directory - I get a lot of compilation errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `import "battery_saver_mode_enum.proto";` and do not care about this hint-error.
It is not a compilation error.
If you build it - your import works and you will not get any compilation errors about this import.

The [proto3 Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions) also tells to use import this way

Comment: In my case, I had to move my `import`s above the `option`s and I had another broken `import` somewhere downstream.